# In Chicago style with footnote can we use footnote for additional information?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

I'm using Chicago style with footnote for referencing ( a short form of reference place in footnote).

I wanted to know can I also use footnote for additional information?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you would like?

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what exactly you are asking. Can you be a bit more specific, please? It doesn't have to be in general terms. An example of what you are thinking about would really help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can also use footnotes for additional information if you use the chicago style formatting - just use `\footnote{}`.